# Using dcast.data.table with date values and aggregation

Tags: r, data.table, dcast

Trying to figure this out.  Suppose you have a data.table:

```
dt <- data.table (person=c('bob', 'bob', 'bob'), 
                  door=c('front door', 'front door', 'front door'),
                  type=c('timeIn', 'timeIn', 'timeOut'),
                  time=c(
as.POSIXct('2016 12 02 06 05 01', format = '%Y %m %d %H %M %S'),
as.POSIXct('2016 12 02 06 05 02', format = '%Y %m %d %H %M %S'),
as.POSIXct('2016 12 02 06 05 03', format = '%Y %m %d %H %M %S')                     )
)
```

I want to pivot it to look like this

```
person        door        timeIn             timeOut

bob           front door  min(<date/time>) max(<date/time>)
```

I can't seem to get the right syntax for dcast.data.table.  I tried

```
dcast.data.table(
  dt, person + door ~ type, 
  value.var = 'time', 
  fun.aggregate = function(x) ifelse(type == 'timeIn', min(x), max(x))
)
```

which throws an error:

> Aggregating function(s) should take vector inputs and return a single value (length=1).

I also tried:

```
 dcast.data.table(dt, person + door ~ type, value.var = 'time')
```

But the result throws away my dates

```
   person       door timeIn timeOut
1:    bob front door      2       1
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve the desired result using `dcast`. *jazzurro*'s solution does the aggregation before reshaping the result. The approaches here use `dcast` directly but may require some post-processing. We are using *jazzurro*'s data which are tweaked to obey the `UTC` time zone and CRAN version 1.10.0 of `data.table`.

### 1. Getting `ifelse` to work

As reported in the Q,

```
dcast(
  dt, person + door ~ type, 
  value.var = 'time', 
  fun.aggregate = function(x) ifelse(type == 'timeIn', min(x), max(x))
)
```

returns an error message. The full text of the error message includes the hint to use the `fill` parameter. Unfortunately, `ifelse()` doesn't respect the `POSIXct` class (for details see `?ifelse`) so this needs to be enforced.

With

```
dcast(
  dt, person + door ~ type, 
  value.var = 'time', 
  fun.aggregate = function(x) 
    lubridate::as_datetime(ifelse(type == 'timeIn', min(x), max(x))),
  fill = 0
)
```

we do get

```
#   person       door              timeIn             timeOut
#1:    ana front door 2016-12-02 07:06:01 2016-12-02 07:06:05
#2:    bob front door 2016-12-02 06:05:01 2016-12-02 06:05:05
```

### 2. Alternative to `ifelse`

`ifelse`'s help page suggests

```
(tmp <- yes; tmp[!test] <- no[!test]; tmp)
```

as alternative. Following this advice,

```
dcast(
  dt, person + door ~ type, 
  value.var = 'time', 
  fun.aggregate = function(x) {
    test <- type == "timeIn"; tmp <- min(x); tmp[!test] = max(x)[!test]; tmp
    }
)
```

returns

```
#   person       door              timeIn             timeOut
#1:    ana front door 2016-12-02 07:06:01 2016-12-02 07:06:05
#2:    bob front door 2016-12-02 06:05:01 2016-12-02 06:05:05
```

Note that neither the `fill` parameter nor the coercion to `POSIXct` is needed.

### 3. Using enhanced `dcast`

With the latest versions of `dcast.data.table` we can provide a list of functions to `fun.aggregate`:

```
dcast(dt, person + door ~ type, value.var = 'time', fun = list(min, max))
```

returns

```
#   person       door     time_min_timeIn    time_min_timeOut     time_max_timeIn    time_max_timeOut
#1:    ana front door 2016-12-02 07:06:01 2016-12-02 07:06:03 2016-12-02 07:06:02 2016-12-02 07:06:05
#2:    bob front door 2016-12-02 06:05:01 2016-12-02 06:05:03 2016-12-02 06:05:02 2016-12-02 06:05:05
```

We can remove the unwanted columns and rename the others by

```
dcast(dt, person + door ~ type, value.var = 'time', fun = list(min, max))[
  , .(person, door, timeIn = time_min_timeIn, timeOut = time_max_timeOut)]
```

which gets us

```
#   person       door              timeIn             timeOut
#1:    ana front door 2016-12-02 07:06:01 2016-12-02 07:06:05
#2:    bob front door 2016-12-02 06:05:01 2016-12-02 06:05:05
```

### Data

As mentioned above, we are using *jazzurro*'s data

```
dt <- structure(list(person = c("bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "ana", 
"ana", "ana", "ana"), door = c("front door", "front door", "front door", 
"front door", "front door", "front door", "front door", "front door"
), type = c("timeIn", "timeIn", "timeOut", "timeOut", "timeIn", 
"timeIn", "timeOut", "timeOut"), time = structure(c(1480658701, 
1480658702, 1480658703, 1480658705, 1480662361, 1480662362, 1480662363, 
1480662365), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("person", 
"door", "type", "time"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

but coerce the time zone to `UTC`.

With

```
dt[, time := lubridate::with_tz(time, "UTC")]
```

we have

```
dt
#   person       door    type                time
#1:    bob front door  timeIn 2016-12-02 06:05:01
#2:    bob front door  timeIn 2016-12-02 06:05:02
#3:    bob front door timeOut 2016-12-02 06:05:03
#4:    bob front door timeOut 2016-12-02 06:05:05
#5:    ana front door  timeIn 2016-12-02 07:06:01
#6:    ana front door  timeIn 2016-12-02 07:06:02
#7:    ana front door timeOut 2016-12-02 07:06:03
#8:    ana front door timeOut 2016-12-02 07:06:05
```

independent of local time zone.

Comment: Strange because Uwe Block's solution appeared to work yesterday but now running into an error

dcast(
  dt, person + door ~ type, 
  value.var = 'time', 
  fun.aggregate = function(x) 
    lubridate::as_datetime(ifelse(type == 'timeIn', min(x), max(x))),
  fill = 0
)

throws an error "error in ifelse (...) object 'type' not found

Comment: Note - the reason for this is you need to use dcast.data.table instead of just dcast

Comment: As long as `dt` is a `data.table` a simple `dcast` should suffice, I believe.

Answer (score 6):

This would be one way to achieve your goal. I modified your `dt` and created the following data set. For each person, I looked for the minimum time of `timeIn` and the maximum time of `timeOut`. Then, I applied `dcast()` to the result.

```
#   person       door    type                time
#1:    bob front door  timeIn 2016-12-02 06:05:01
#2:    bob front door  timeIn 2016-12-02 06:05:02
#3:    bob front door timeOut 2016-12-02 06:05:03
#4:    bob front door timeOut 2016-12-02 06:05:05
#5:    ana front door  timeIn 2016-12-02 07:06:01
#6:    ana front door  timeIn 2016-12-02 07:06:02
#7:    ana front door timeOut 2016-12-02 07:06:03
#8:    ana front door timeOut 2016-12-02 07:06:05

library(data.table)

dcast(
   dt[, .SD[(type == "timeIn" & time == min(time))|(type == "timeOut" & time == max(time))], by = person],
   person + door ~ type)

#   person       door              timeIn             timeOut
#1:    ana front door 2016-12-02 07:06:01 2016-12-02 07:06:05
#2:    bob front door 2016-12-02 06:05:01 2016-12-02 06:05:05
```

DATA

```
dt <- structure(list(person = c("bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "ana", 
"ana", "ana", "ana"), door = c("front door", "front door", "front door", 
"front door", "front door", "front door", "front door", "front door"
), type = c("timeIn", "timeIn", "timeOut", "timeOut", "timeIn", 
"timeIn", "timeOut", "timeOut"), time = structure(c(1480658701, 
1480658702, 1480658703, 1480658705, 1480662361, 1480662362, 1480662363, 
1480662365), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("person", 
"door", "type", "time"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: There may be a time-zone issue, but when using your `dt` structure I get different `time` values to those in your example

Comment: @SymbolixAU Yeah, that should happen. I am not in your time zone.

Comment: @SymbolixAU I specified tz = "UTC" when I created the sample data. I wonder if you can reproduce the same results by specifying that time zone.

Comment: Not by reading it in directly; I have to convert it to numeric, then to POSIXct specifying `tz =  "UTC"` this end.

Comment: @SymbolixAU I see. Thanks for that. :)